# Reformatting Dataframe Containing Array to RowMatrix

Tags: pyspark

I have this dataframe in the following format:

```
+----+-----+
| features |
+----+-----+
|[1,4,7,10]|
|[2,5,8,11]|
|[3,6,9,12]|
+----+----+
```

Script to create sample dataframe:

```
rows2 = sc.parallelize([ IndexedRow(0, [1, 4, 7, 10 ]),
                         IndexedRow(1, [2, 5, 8, 1]),
                         IndexedRow(1, [3, 6, 9, 12]),
                                   ])
rows_df = rows2.toDF()
row_vec= rows_df.drop("index")
row_vec.show()
```

The feature column contains 4 features, and there are 3 row ids. I want to convert this data to a rowmatrix, where the columns and rows will be in the following mat format:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix
rows = sc.parallelize([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)])

# Convert to RowMatrix
mat = RowMatrix(rows)

# Calculate exact and approximate similarities
exact = mat.columnSimilarities()
approx = mat.columnSimilarities(0.05)
```

Basically, I want to transpose the dataframe into the new format so that I can run the columnSimilarities() function. I have a much larger dataframe that contains 50 features, and 39000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?  Hate using `collect()` but don't think it can be avoided here since you want to reshape/convert structured object to matrix ... right?

```
X = np.array(row_vec.select("_2").collect()).reshape(-1,3)
X = sc.parallelize(X)
for i in X.collect(): print(i)
[1 4 7]
[10  2  5]
[8 1 3]
[ 6  9 12]
```

Comment: I need to transpose the dataframe and then turn it into a rowMatrix to be fed into the function

Comment: I think that is what my example is doing ... essentially you are just trying to reshape the dimensions as N rows and 3 cols ... right?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I used the following:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix


features_rdd = row_vec.select("features").rdd.map(lambda row: row[0])

features_mat = RowMatrix(features_rdd )

from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import CoordinateMatrix, MatrixEntry

coordmatrix_features  = CoordinateMatrix(
        features_mat .rows.zipWithIndex().flatMap(
        lambda x: [MatrixEntry(x[1], j, v) for j, v in enumerate(x[0])]
        )
         )
transposed_rowmatrix_features = coordmatrix_features.transpose().toRowMatrix()
```